# Does pandas categorical data speed up indexing?

Tags: pandas

Somebody told me it is a good idea to convert identifying columns (e.g. person numbers) from strings to categorical. This would speed up some operations like searching, filtering and grouping.

I understand that a 40 chars strings costs much more RAM and time to compare instead of a simple integer.

But I would have some overhead because of a str-to-int-table for translating between two types and to know which integer number belongs to which string "number".

Maybe `.astype('categorical')` can help me here? Isn't this an integer internally? Does this speed up some operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) has the following about categorical data use cases:

> The categorical data type is useful in the following cases:
>
> - A string variable consisting of only a few different values.    Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save some memory, see here.
> - The lexical order of a variable is not the same as the logical order    (“one”, “two”, “three”). By converting to a categorical and specifying an order on the categories, sorting and min/max will use the logical order instead of the lexical order, see here.
> - As a signal to other Python libraries that this column should be    treated as a categorical variable (e.g. to use suitable statistical methods or plot types).
>
> See also the API docs on categoricals.

The book, [Python for Data Analysis](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/) by Wes McKinney, has the following on this topic:

> The categorical representation can yield significant performance
> improvements when you are doing analytics. You can also perform
> transformations on the categories while leaving the codes unmodified.
> Some example transformations that can be made at relatively low cost are:
>
> - Renaming categories
> - Appending a new category without changing the order or position of the existing categories

> GroupBy operations can be significantly faster with categoricals because the underlying algorithms use the integer-based codes array instead of an array of strings.

> Series containing categorical data have several special methods similar to the Series.str specialized string methods. This also provides convenient access to the categories and codes.

> In large datasets, categoricals are often used as a convenient tool for memory savings and better performance.

Comment: Then I wonder. ~3 Mio. lines (~40 cols), the index column is `str` with 40chars. `groupby()` took ~ 3 minutes. When the column is `category` it took ~20 min. I think I have to setup an MWE with sample data to reproduce this.