# Is there a natural way to handle values of Enum class in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

Enum classes are often defined as a mapping from names to numeric constants. I was looking to take advantage of this mapping to show natural labels in a categorical pandas column, while keeping the numbers for efficiency.

Initially I felt this could be achieved naturally by using the [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) type, so I started working from the following approach:

```py
from enum import IntEnum
import pandas as pd

class CategoryType(IntEnum):
  RED = 0
  YELLOW = 1
  GREEN = 2

cat = pd.Categorical([2,2,1,2,0], categories = [x for x in CategoryType])
cat_data = pd.DataFrame(cat)
```

The above will work, but all of the label information is of course lost so you only see the numbers when printing the data frame.

We can use `map` or other similar transformations to make everything work with `str` types, but this seems like a huge waste of time given that `Categorical` is already supposed to store internally strings as numerical codes, so it seems backwards to do this when we already have the codes.

Furthermore, you lose all ability to do something like the following `cat_data == CategoryType.Red` since your categorical will be string based and so knows nothing about numbers.

I've searched everywhere but for some reason I can only find suggestions about mapping from numbers to categorical strings, but never about preserving the numbers from an existing Enum type and somehow assigning labels to the codes for display purposes.

I was a bit surprised by this since it looks to me like this would be something people want to do fairly often. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `Categorical` itself provides a utility function to efficiently construct categorical columns from previously encoded enum mappings: [`from_codes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.from_codes.html)

Using it we can efficiently do the following:

```py
from enum import IntEnum
import pandas as pd

class CategoryType(IntEnum):
  RED = 0
  YELLOW = 1
  GREEN = 2

cat = pd.Categorical.from_codes(
  [2,2,1,2,0],
  categories = [x.name for x in CategoryType])
cat_data = pd.DataFrame(cat)
```

Then for comparison we can do:

```py
cat_data == CategoryType.RED.name
```

A pity that we cannot use the enum value directly in the comparisons, but at least we eliminate entirely the need to use `apply` and other more costly mappings to initialize the categorical.

A few limitations/caveats of this approach:

- codes are interpreted as 0-based indices into the array of categories, so you need to make sure all your Enum values start at zero and increment by 1
- from above, this means no support for bit-flags, i.e. [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) style will not work

Comment: still beautiful

Comment: You could prolly use `cat_data[0].cat.codes == CategoryType.RED` if you want to use the enum value and not CategoryType.RED.name

Comment: oh that's right, i'd totally missed that!

Answer (score 0):

`.name` attribute of enum members may help to get enum strings directly.

**Code:**

```
data = [2, 2, 1, 2, 0]
cat_data = pd.DataFrame({'Category': data})
cat_data['Category_Label'] = cat_data['Category'].apply(lambda x: CategoryType(x).name)
```

**Output:**

```
   Category Category_Label
0         2          GREEN
1         2          GREEN
2         1         YELLOW
3         2          GREEN
4         0            RED
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right the main reason why you dont want to use the strings "GREEN" "RED" "YELLOW" in your dataframe is because of efficency/Performance. In this case pandas categories might be exactly what you are looking for.

With pandas categories there is no need to use the redundancy that you are trying to implement. You are trying to put `CategoryType(IntEnum)` into `pandas categories`. This is unnecessary, you can just use  `pd.Categorical(["GREEN","GREEN","RED"...], categories =["RED","GREEN","YELLOW"])` and get best performance.

Actually this use case is exactly what categories are made for. The number of colors you have consists only of a few different values and let panda algorithm take advantage of that.

Using categories has the following advantages (among others):

- GroupBy operations can be significantly faster with categoricals
  because the underlying algorithms use the integer-based codes array
  instead of an array of strings.
- A string variable consisting of only a few different values.
  Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save
  some memory, see here.

More info here [Stackoverflow, Does pandas categorical data speed up indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526472/does-pandas-categorical-data-speed-up-indexing)

Comment: I understand your argument, the problem is that I have numerical arrays to begin with. To do it as you suggest would require mapping the numbers first back to strings, so that Categorical can then "optimize" it. In a way I already have the map. Luckily it does seem someone thought of something like this with the `from_codes` function. My answer below describes how to use it.